# Cannot redeclare non static PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$dependencies as static SapphireTest::$dependencies

Tags: silverstripe

I'm getting the following error when running dev/build?flush=all on a new SilverStripe installation, installed via composer, running on an Ubuntu Precise (12.04) Vagrant VM:

```
Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare non static PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$dependencies as static SapphireTest::$dependencies in /var/www/silverstripe/framework/dev/SapphireTest.php on line 12
Stack trace:
1. {main}() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/main.php:0
2. Director::direct() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/main.php:189
3. Director::handleRequest() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Director.php:152
4. Controller->handleRequest() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Director.php:366
5. RequestHandler->handleRequest() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Controller.php:153
6. Controller->handleAction() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/RequestHandler.php:200
7. RequestHandler->handleAction() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Controller.php:194
8. DevelopmentAdmin->build() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/RequestHandler.php:288
9. Controller->handleRequest() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/dev/DevelopmentAdmin.php:146
10. RequestHandler->handleRequest() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Controller.php:153
11. Controller->handleAction() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/RequestHandler.php:200
12. RequestHandler->handleAction() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/Controller.php:194
13. DatabaseAdmin->index() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/control/RequestHandler.php:288
14. DatabaseAdmin->build() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/model/DatabaseAdmin.php:80
15. DatabaseAdmin->doBuild() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/model/DatabaseAdmin.php:100
16. class_exists() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/model/DatabaseAdmin.php:204
17. SS_ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:0
18. require_once() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:77
19. SS_ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:0
20. require_once() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:77
21. SS_ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:0
22. require_once() /var/www/silverstripe/framework/core/manifest/ClassLoader.php:77
```

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.*",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.*",
        "undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600  
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of PHPUnit is too old. You need to be running at least 3.5.8, though preferably newer.